# JavaScript Fetch API can you access headers as well as JSON in a `.then ` callback?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, response-headers

I need to make a POST request and then depending on the response as well as the headers, I need to update saved state, I know the headers are available via `response.header.get('SOME-KEY')` and I can access JSON part of the response in a `.then` callback like so: `.then(response => response.json()).then(json =>())`

what I want to know is, is there a way to get both in the block which has the parsed JSON response data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know how I missed this, the solution was extremely simple, `.json()` returns a `Promise`, so we can just call `.then` on it inside the current context and do what we want with the headers and the response body:

```js
fetch('/url')
  .then(response => response.json().then(json => ({...json, token: response.headers.get('TOKEN')})))
  .then(json => props.updateUser(json));
```

In this way we can get the desired object which contains the header values as well as the response data. *Sometimes all you need to solve your problem is a bit of sleep.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

```
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
    console.log(response.headers)
})
```

https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema

Comment: I am looking to access parsed json part of the response, so I can dispatch it along with a header using a redux action creator like: `props.updateUser({...json, token: response.header.get('TOKEN')});`

Comment: So what is the problem of doing that? Get the json from `response.data` and merge it with the token.